# More efficient to directly assign or pull from XML?

Tags: android, xml

I am currently trying to reduce my GC overhead size.

I noticed that I have several of my keys for my bundle were directly assigned to a String at the start of the code and then uses the assignment later. For example:

```
String NewTimeKey = "NewTimeKey";
```

Is it better if I store the String in a resource XML and call for it at the start of my program like this?

```
String NewTimeKey = getString(R.string.NewTimeKey);
```

Comment: So you think that there is connection between *GC overhead* and Bundles keys? just leave the keys alone (as static final strings)... even if you had 1000 keys with len ~500 its only about 1MB

Comment: huh, so I'm screwing up big time somewhere else then. Thanks for the heads up, though!

Comment: [Use some memory analizer to check what data takes the most memory](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)